# Cannot add color to character on multiple lines using Ncurses mvchgat

Tags: c++, c, terminal, ncurses

I'm trying to color a video game map in Ncurses using a loop to have a specific color for multiple characters, it works fine on a single line but whenever I try to apply color to multiple lines either it doesn't apply any color, or it only applies color on the last line.

Here's my code:

```
initscr();
start_color();
char *map =  strdup("OOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOO\nBXXXOXXXOXOXXXXOXXB\nOXXXOXXXOXOXXXXOXXO\nOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\nOXXXOXOXXXXXOXXOXXO\nOOOOOXOOOXOOOXXOOOO\nXXXXOXXXOXOXXXXOXXX\nXXXXOXOOOOOOOXXOXXX\nXXXXOXOMMMMMOXXOXXX\nXXXXOOOMMMMMOOOOXXX\nXXXXOXOMMMMMOXXOXXX\nXXXXOXOOOOOOOXXOXXX\nXXXXOXOXXXXXOXXOXXX\nOOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOO\nOXXXOXXXOXOXXXXOXXO\nBOOXOOOOOOOOOOOOXOB\nXXOXOXOXXXXXOXXOXOX\nOOOOOXOOOXOOOXXOOOO\nOXXXXXXXOXOXXXXXXXO\nOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
init_pair(1, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
while (true) {
    mvprintw(0, 0, map);
    for (int i = 0; y < 19; i++, x++) {
        if (x == 19) {
            y++;
            x = 0;
        }
        if (map[i] == 'O') {
            mvchgat(map[i], y, x, 1, A_BLINK, 2, NULL);
        }
        else if (map[i] == 'X') {
            mvchgat(y, x, 1, A_BLINK, 1, NULL);
        }
        else if (map[i] == 'B'){
            mvchgat(y, x, 1, A_BLINK, 3, NULL);
        }
        refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` in the string erases the next line(s), wiping out the video attributes.

`mvprintw` (and `printw`, etc), ultimately call [`waddch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html), which documents the behavior:

> - *Newline*  does  a **`clrtoeol`**, then moves the cursor to the window left
>   margin on the next line, scrolling the window if on the last line.

Comment: I removed the \n and used mvprintw to print on different lines in a loop, thanks !